# What's the opposite of "precede"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, antonyms

In the particular context that I'm in, I was writing about several lines of programming.  For simplicity, let's call them:

```
line a
line b
```

First, I described `line a`.  Great.  Then I wanted to write about `line b`, but couldn't think of the way to describe the relationship between `b` and `a`.  The closest I could think of was "follows", but to say "the following line" is ambiguous: it can refer to either the line of code after `line a`, or it can imply that I'm going to copy and paste `line b` into my text and reference it there (which was not the case).

I ended up saying something to the effect of "`line a` precedes some code that...", but was wondering:

If `line a` "precedes" `line b`, then what is the proper and unambiguous term for the relationship between `line b`, relative to `line a`?  Postcede?

Comment: Succeed or follow. Online thesaurus.

Comment: Parliament is changing the law.  Now, the eldest child (of either gender) will **succeed** the monarch.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Line B is preceded by Line A.
>
> Line A is followed by Line B.

EDIT after the first comment:

To make it active, you can try:

> Line B follows Line A.

Alternatively, you could say:

> Line B comes after Line A.

Comment: Ah, I like "comes after".  What about an adjective form?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? I think you're looking for "the preceding line" and "the following line", or alternatively, "the succeeding line".

Comment: comes immediately after?  immediately follows, or similar? :)

Answer (score 12):

The most natural-sounding way you could say it (other than using "follows") is probably: "is next after".

If "line A" precedes "line B", "line B" is/comes next after "line A".

"Succeed" is the technical antonym to "precede", but "line B succeeds line A" does not sound as natural.

Then again, though you discarded the term "follows", it may turn out to be a good choice.

Comment: predecessor/successor ... follower has another meaning

Answer (score 1):

Antecede is synonymous with precede (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/antecede). I believe the proper "mirror word" to precede is succeed. This usage is most commonly seen in the form predecessor/successor, but it's perfectly valid to say that line a precedes line b and line b succeeds line a.

Comment: Welcome to the site, but your suggestion of *succeed* has already been given and the commentary about *antecede* would be more suitable as a comment, not an answer. If you are new to Stack Exchange, I encourage you to visit the [Help Center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help)— this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.

Answer (score 1):

From etymological view "succeed" is antonym for "precede" but at least in [oxforddictionaries.com](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/succeed) this meaning is last meaning in modern English which in this sense synonyms are "follow", "come after", "follow after".

Answer (score -1):

"Subsequent" is a fitting antonym to precede.

Comment: How fitting can it be as it isn't even a verb?

Answer (score -4):

I see the question the inquirer is driving at. The word "precede" means to walk "in advance of" or "in front of". He/she is asking if there is a mirror word (presumably utilizing the root word "cede"), for "precede". A single word that means, essentially, "to walk behind" or "to follow", or "the last in a train of..."

That word, dear asker, is not "postcede", though I see your logic, but "antecede".

Comment: But antecede is actually a synonym of precede: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/antecede